# Find decimal mark character based on locale

Tags: ios, nslocale

The decimal mark can be a dot or comma based on the locale. How can I determine which one it is?

I have read through the docs on Formatting Data Using the Locale Settings but cannot figure out how do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways. Get the `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` attribute from `NSLocale` or use the `decimalSeparator` property from `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *separator = [formatter decimalSeparator];
```

or:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *separator = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
```

Both of these examples assume you want to work with the user's default locale.